# Py "permission denied" when running bash script

Tags: python, bash, paramiko, openssh

i made a script that connect to a ssh server using paramiko, and after using some bash command stored inside a bash script copy and take some data files, after that using the command line i use another command to copy the datas from ssh server(SVN) loccally. all works, but when im running the py script its says permission denined

**The error that im receiving when i`m using the script is:**
[image: script error "permission denied on files"]

**The error its not about bash.py "permission denied, cause i did that echo "bash its works" to verify if the commands works inside the bash.**

**The py script:**

```
import paramiko
import os
hostname = "LOGIN AND CONECTION WORKS!"
username = ""
password = ""

# initialize the SSH client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# add to known hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
    print("Connection was established!")
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    exit()

# read the BASH script content from the file
bash_script = open("Collect-Usage-SVN.sh").read()
# execute the BASH script
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(bash_script)
# read the standard output and print it
print(stdout.read().decode())
# print errors if there are any
err = stderr.read().decode()
if err:
    print(err)
# execute cmd command to copy files locally
os.chdir('D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\svnrawdatas')
os.system("start cmd /K scp root@atpcnd6c:/data/audit/2022-07-08-* .")
client.close()
```

**THIS IS THE BASH_SCRIPT.SH:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
echo "Bash script its running"

CurrentDate=$(date +"%F")
RawDataFolder="/data/audit"
svnLOGFILE="/data/audit/log-svn-usage-data-collection.log"

#echo "Timestamp when starting the work $(date +"%D %T")" >> $svnLOGFILE
echo "Timestamp when starting the work $(date +"%F %T")" >> $svnLOGFILE

# Collect raw data
echo "Generating raw SVN usage data" >> $svnLOGFILE

cp -v /data/conf/mod_authrewrite.map $RawDataFolder/$CurrentDate-svnRawData-mod_authrewrite.map.txt >> $svnLOGFILE;
cp -v /data/conf/svn_authorization.conf $RawDataFolder/$CurrentDate-svnRawData-authorization.conf.txt >> $svnLOGFILE;
cut -d: -f1 /data/conf/localauthfile.htpasswd > $RawDataFolder/$CurrentDate-svnRawData-localauthfile.htpasswd.txt
cd /data/svn; ls -ltr /data/svn | du -h --max-depth=1 > /data/audit/2022-05-06-svnRawData-repositoriesSize.csv;
for repo in /data/svn/*; do  echo $repo; svnlook date $repo; done > $RawDataFolder/$CurrentDate-svnRawData-repositoriesLastChangeDate.csv;

echo "Finished generating raw data" >> $svnLOGFILE

echo "Timestamp when work is finished $(date +"%D %T")" >> $svnLOGFILE
echo "Happy data analysis !" >> $svnLOGFILE
echo "***********************************************************************************" >> $svnLOGFILE
echo "/n" >> svnLOGFILE
```

**on first line also i used also : #!/usr/bin/env
This is how i runn the script on the server directly on the bash shell command:**

```
Run the SVN script like this
/data/audit/Collect-Usage-SVN.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**The below command is used in CMD terminal to copy the files from server on locall disk**

```
Copy SVN and GIT raw files from SVN server to local Windows
scp root@user:/data/audit/2022-07-08-* .
(see example in Copy_from_SVN_server.jpeg)
```

Comment: So if you run your script via `ssh` (instead of Python/Paramiko), does it work? Like this: `ssh username@hostname < Collect-Usage-SVN.sh`? Show us what does this result to.

Comment: hi martin, yes if i run the script via ss its works, so bassicly the bash.sh script its copying,colecting and storage the datas and after i use the cmd command below to copy the datas from the ssh svn server loccaly on disk

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you do that.

Comment: i will come tommorow with 2 photos about how i do it, but i do as i detaild above i open the ssh, and after i execute the bash script with that command and after i just open the cmd line on windows and execut the next command.

Comment: I've asked you if THIS works: `ssh username@hostname < Collect-Usage-SVN.sh` – EXACTLY THIS. Not, ssh and then some command. + Why are you trying to run a local script in Python, when normally in `ssh` you run a remote script?

Comment: cause i make an app that automatize some system, and now i want to create this py script to automatically connect to ssh svn server , colect,and take data from remote server to loccal disk

Comment: Ok, so does `ssh username@hostname < Collect-Usage-SVN.sh` work?

Comment: sorry, do you have a discord? @MartinPrikryl , i runned the script like "./collect-usage-svn.s" and worked like but with "ssh username@hostname" idk how, i never used just now i use the ssh with paramiko and the bash for this automatisation